# Is there a standard Icon / logo for NFC

Tags: standards, nfc

I am developing an application that makes use of NFC (near field communication). And i want to prompt a screen for the user to swipe the NFC tag.

So i want to know if there is a standard image for NFC. Like I know usb has one [image: here]

If not, then I guess I will just have to choose one.

Comment: No there isn't as such. The icon SHOULD BE the NFC logo in my opinion. However the one i see a lot is one much like this http://cdn.slashgear.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/nfcc.gif . You will find it on payment devices e.c.t. and the icon describes the action. So i'd go with that one, it's used commonly enough to be recognisable, and the icon describes the action required for those that don't recognise it. If you google image for `nfc payment` you will see an icon like this on a number of physical devices that pictured.

Comment: @Lee I tend to agree with you on the describes the action part. Because as suggested below, The N-Mark icon does not depict any sort of wireless or any sort of action that is required.

Comment: Note that the logo mentioned by @Lee specifically indicates contactless payments using EMV payment standards. The logo seems to be a trademark of EMVCo (see http://www.emvco.com/best_practices.aspx?id=117).

Answer (score 2):

According to the NFC Forum, there is. You have to register to use it.

http://www.nfc-forum.org/resources/N-Mark

[image: The logo.]
<sub>(source: [wikimedia.org](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/c/c3/NFC-N-Mark-Logo.png))</sub>

Answer (score 2):

NFC Forum create a trademark for NFC, whith logo :

[image: NFC N-Mark Logo]

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:NFC-N-Mark-Logo.png